# How to update a record in SQLite with Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to update a record in SQLite with Android?

Hello.

I write because I am unfortunately stuck in my project and I hope you can help me.
How do I update a record in a database?

For example in a contact database. In this database of contacts, the following keys are used: name, phone, email and address; my problem is when I need to modify a record, what must I do to modify a record.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

This is the SQLite code to update the registry:

```
// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

This same code I have found on many websites, but my problem is how to call the code from the MainActivity with Java.

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial, I double checked and is what you are looking for: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` is designed to be used as a singleton. After implementing it as a singleton, you can access any of it's methods from there.

Answer (score 0):

1- create an instance from ur database in  the main activity:

```
DBhelper db = new DBhelper(this);
```

2- call open:

```
db.open();
```

3- set the update method:

```
db.updateContact(name,phone);
```

4- close the database connection:

```
db.close();
```

5- open and close function in ur database helper class:

```
public DBhelper open() throws SQLException {
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

6- also you gotta define those as global variables:

```
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
```

my advice to you is not to depend on written code you gotta learn to write it ur self specially database creation and usage it is really important so here is a good tutorial for you, you could benefit from it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm.
Good luck

Comment: There is no `open()` method in `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: i edited it to include open and close methods, check it out :)

Comment: Why would you define a separate `open()` method when there is no need? `SQLiteOpenHelper` was designed so as not require opening the `SQLiteDatabase` at centralized point. Also, why would there be a local `mDbHelper` variable inside the object itself?

Comment: its a convention to use open and close as a separated methods it will make ur code easier to use,read and more efficient.

Comment: and for the mdbHelper part you got it all wrong, this variable is essential to Define a constructor for the DatabaseHandler class which will create an object of the inner class databseHandler (it takes context as an argument). Ofcourse you will need to define an object of your inner class DatabaseHandler before that all of that.

Comment: i really adivce you not waste your time more than that and start studying the tutorials that i put in the answer, it is really important to understand the process of creating databases in android using sqlite before talking about it and ofc before using it. Good luck and happy new year

Comment: I haven't seen such a convention for `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and in fact that's the very convention it's trying to bypass. If you are accessing a singleton variable, then the method and variable should be static - however, the method doesn't need to be static if the class is a singleton. I am not the person who asked the question, and I'm just pointing out some issues in your answer.